# anyone know how to run a vba macro from python?

Tags: python, vba, cad

i have the following macro in vba to make a part in solidworks. I have the question if from python I can execute the macro without having to go to solidworks and execute it from there

I have tried to find information, but nothing appears about what I am looking for

I would appreciate if someone can help me

```
Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks
Dim swDoc As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
Dim BoolStatus As Boolean
Dim swSketchManager As SldWorks.SketchManager
Dim longstatus As Long, longwarnings As Long
Dim Part As Object


Sub Main()

    Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
    
    
    Dim defaultTemplate As String
    
    defaultTemplate = swApp.GetUserPreferenceStringValue(swUserPreferenceStringValue_e.swDefaultTemplatePart)
    
    Set swDoc = swApp.NewDocument(defaultTemplate, 0, 0, 0)
    
    BoolStatus = swDoc.Extension.SelectByID2("Front", "PLANE", 0, 0, 0, False, 0, Nothing, swSelectOption_e.swSelectOptionDefault)
    
        
        
    Set swSketchManager = swDoc.SketchManager
    
    Dim mySketchSegment As SldWorks.SketchSegment
    
    swSketchManager.InsertSketch True
    
    Set mySketchSegment = swSketchManager.CreateLine(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
    
    Set mySketchSegment = swSketchManager.CreateLine(0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0)
    
    Set mySketchSegment = swSketchManager.CreateLine(2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0)
    
    Set mySketchSegment = swSketchManager.CreateLine(2, 2, 0, 4, 2, 0)
    
    Set mySketchSegment = swSketchManager.CreateLine(4, 2, 0, 4, 1, 0)
    
    Set mySketchSegment = swSketchManager.CreateLine(4, 1, 0, 6, 1, 0)
    
    Set mySketchSegment = swSketchManager.CreateLine(6, 1, 0, 6, 0, 0)
    
    Set mySketchSegment = swSketchManager.CreateLine(0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0)
    
    swDoc.ClearSelection2 True
    
    Set Part = swApp.ActiveDoc

    ' Named View
    Part.ShowNamedView2 "*Trimétrica", 8
    Part.ViewZoomtofit2
    BoolStatus = Part.Extension.SelectByID2("Line8", "SKETCHSEGMENT", 2.27939213179474, 0.424565217882254, 0.640103542052883, True, 0, Nothing, 0)
    Part.ClearSelection2 True
    BoolStatus = Part.Extension.SelectByID2("Line8", "SKETCHSEGMENT", 2.27939213179474, 0.424565217882254, 0.640103542052883, False, 16, Nothing, 0)
    Dim myFeature As Object
    Set myFeature = Part.FeatureManager.FeatureRevolve2(True, True, False, False, False, False, 0, 0, 6.2831853071796, 0, False, False, 0.01, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, True, True, True)
    Part.SelectionManager.EnableContourSelection = False
    Part.SetPickMode
    Part.ClearSelection2 True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: The excel VBA code here is less relevant. The code you want to share is your attempt in Python. Cheap ways to do this are by utilizing vba events (workbook.open) but you probably should be more explicit since that is only valid in narrow use cases

Comment: Using the module `subprocess` would be another option.